# How does font fallback work on a non-Windows OS?

Tags: c#, .net, fonts, internationalization

I have been reading a lot of documentation on how to create an internationalised ASP.NET application, using C# 3.5. They all seem to give the general impression that font fallback and font linking will make font choice a non-issue.

However, the documentation I have seems to imply that it will be fine on Windows, but doesn't mention other OSs, like for the Mac and Linux.

> There is no font that supports all characters for all languages, but if your clients are using Windows 2000 or later, it is sufficient to use a single font throughout an application due to font linking and font fallback. This means that your system will determine a font appropriate for the machine's culture. ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb688134.aspx))

Will this magically work on a Mac/Linux, or is there some extra legwork involved in supporting these platforms?

Comment: Is is ASP.NET or Windows Forms?

Answer (score 1):

If your application isn't producing any sort of documents like PDFs, Excel files or whatnot ASP.Net isn't really responsible for font handling. CSS will be.

Answer (score 1):

For web applications, you have to specify that font fallback yourself, in your CSS files using the `font-family` directive - [documentation for which is available at W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#font-family)